# Error trying to run Rmd file on Kaggle Kernel

Tags: r, kernel, r-markdown, kaggle

This is the first time I try to create something on a Kaggle Kernel. I know Rmd files are special as they have regular text and code on them. I read that I can't use the usual blue arrow to run the code on the Kernel because it will also try to run the regular text, on my case, generating this error:

```
    Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

How am I supposed to run Rmd files within Kaggle to view the report it generates?

I tried to reload the kernel and search for a special button to run the entire Rmd file but no luck whatsoever.

```
---
title: "Credit Card Fraud Detection"
author: "Fernando JosÃ© Velasco Borea"
date: "May 12th 2019"
output: 
  pdf_document:
      toc: true
      number_sections: true
---
```

```
x <- 1
print(x)
```

I'm expecting a behavior like the one I get on RStudio, like being able to run the code chunks and if I want, run everything to generate the report.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a markdown (.md) natively with Kaggle kernels. Check out this [example](https://www.kaggle.com/apryor6/making-beautiful-scatter-plots-nfl-2015). However I don't think Kaggle kernel will render the same performance as RStudio.

Comment: Thanks! I can render the file only when I commit, but if I want to just run the file to see it on the console or without commit it just keep generating the error on the console. Check this link to see a screenshot https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/100659

Comment: Unfortunately there's not currently a way to render rmd in the kernel editor.